# unity ads, who controls how often they will be shown, me or Advertisement plugin?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've implemented Unity Ads and have:

```
void Start()
{
    Advertisement.Show();
}
```

In the scrip connected to my unity advertisement GameObject.

When I test my game an advertisement is shown when the scene loads (it a scene that displays results of your game session) and this is what I want, but I don't think it's good to show an advertisement every single time this scene loads, since it will load quite often. Is there some kind of algorithm in the background deciding if the ad should be shown?

I think there should be some kind of limit to how many ads can be shown in x amount of time, not just in unity, but in ads in general, that's why I thought it might be built in already.

So, my question, should I leave it like this, and let the Advertisement plugin to the job, or should I ad some kind of randomizer, like:

```
int number = Random.Range(1, 2);
    if (number == 1) {
        Advertisement.Show();
    }
```

to show the ad about 50% of the time?

Full disclosure, I asked this on the unity forums as well, several days ago, and it has yet to be approved (so it's not published), will probably delete that one.

Comment: I have no answer to your question, but a comment. The `Random` example you posted does not show ads 50% of the time. It has a 50% chance to be shown each time the screen starts, but doesn't guarantee you that it will be shown only 50% of the time :)

Comment: @NahuelIanni No, I get that, it was simply an example to try and prove my thought :), Problem is, I think that when this scene loads is the perfect time for an ad, but I don't want my users to be spammed.. Need to find some middle ground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Disclaimer: I have no experience whatsoever with the Unity Ads
>   framework.

Based on the [blog post](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/04/09/integrating-unity-ads/) made by the Unity team, I would say that a simple solution can be to check if the scene showed ads the last time it was loaded and depending on the situation, show a new one or do nothing at all.

We can do that in two steps:

1. Create a static class for keeping track of when an ad was shown.
2. Determine on your scene whether the condition is met to show a new one or not based on the value of the static class, and update it.

For example:

```
public static class AdvertisementTracker
{
    /// Create a property or method to store and retrieve whether
    /// an advertisement was shown at a given time. 
    /// You can use a bool, datetime, IList<DateTime> or whatever property that you need.

    public static bool AdShown = false;
    public static DateTime LastTimeShown;
    public static IList<DateTime> TimesShown = new List<DateTime>();

    /// You can even have a method that takes the elapsed time between calls and check
    /// if they meet the criteria you wish to show your ads.
    public static bool ElapsedTimeConditionMet(float elapsedTime)
    {
        // For example, the elapsed time exceeds 40 seconds, so a new add can be shown.
        return elapsedTime >= 40.0f;
    }
}
```

Then, on your scene, attach the following script to your advertisement object:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
using System.Collections; 

public class SimpleAdScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Advertisement.Initialize("<the ad ID>", true);     
        StartCoroutine(ShowAdWhenReady());
    }

    IEnumerator ShowAdWhenReady()
    {
        while (!Advertisement.isReady())
            yield return null;

        if(!AdvertisementTracker.AdShown)
        {
            Advertisement.Show();
        }

        AdvertisementTracker.AdShown = !AdvertisementTracker.AdShown;
    }
}
```

The objective of the script is to check if an ad is ready from the Unity framework.
If it is, it then checks if an ad was shown last time. If this is not the case, then it gets shown, otherwise the static class gets updated to be ready for the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, I do have to keep track of all this myself, altough it doesn't seem very complicated. This will show the ad every other time the scene loads, and then I can use the dateTime values for additional checks (say if the scene loads twice in under a minute maybe)

Comment: That's exactly the point. The example is really simple but by using datetimes, you can keep track of how often to show it (say once every 20 minutes), and the boolean allows you to show it 50% of the times.

Comment: I will test this when I get home (at work right now, the unity is a private project) I'm sure this works perfectly, but I'll keep it open until it's tested (made that mistake before, marking something wrong :p )

Comment: Updated the answer with a method in the static class to keep the logic cleaner. Check it out as well (specially if you plan on using the DateTime values to keep track).